# Number of ways of delivering letters

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If you have $10$ addressed letters to deliver. You randomly post the
letters (maximum one per box) in a street which has $25$ mailboxes. In how
many ways can you deliver these letters?

**Attempt**:

Firstly, I think this is a combination because order does not matter. Secondly, repetition is not allowed (stated in the question). So, I will use the classic combination formula:

$\frac{25!}{10!(25 -10)!}$ ways that you can deliver the letters but apparently, my answer is incorrect. Please help.

Comment: "Order does not matter": Tell that to the people receiving the mail!

Answer (score 3):

You should multiply your answer by $10!$ because letters are distinguishable. In your answer, you are only choosing $10$ mailboxes to deliver the letters but letters may also permute. So order actually matters here.

Answer (score 3):

For the first letter we have $\color{blue}{25}$ options.

After posting it in any one of the $25$ boxes, we have $\color{blue}{24}$ options for the second letter, $\color{blue}{23}$ for the third and so on up to the tenth letter.

[image]

So, the number of ways is

> $$\color{red}{n = 25\cdot24\cdot23\cdots16 = \frac{25!}{15!}}$$

Or simply, $$\color{green}{n= \ ^{25}P_{10} = \frac{25!}{15!}}$$